# How to stub/mock return value of a function in php unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

When trying to stub a simple function based on the phpunit documentation [here](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#stubs), it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class A {

    public static function func() {
        $helperData = A::helper();
        return $helperData + 1;
    }

    public static function helper() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Test class

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFunc(): void
    {
        $stub = $this->createStub(A::class);
        $stub->method('helper')
        ->willReturn(2);

       $result = A::func();
       $this->assertEquals(3, $result); // actual result is 6 not 3--why?
    }
}
```

The stubbed function `helper` doesn't return `2` as I specified. Why is this, and how can I successfully mock the return value of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$stub` object instead of `A` class, to get the stubbed function result. You should use non-static method to use this.

```php
<?php 

declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class A {

    public function func() {
        $helperData = $this->helper();
        return $helperData + 1;
    }

    public function helper() {
        return 5;
    }
}

final class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFunc(): void
    {
        $stub = $this->createStub(A::class);

        $stub->method('helper')
            ->willReturn(2);

        $stub->method('func')
            ->willReturn($stub->helper() + 1);

        
        $result = $stub->func(); // Use `$stub->`
        $this->assertEquals(3, $result); // OK
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

---

**EDIT**

---

To use the original code for `func`, you could make it static, and use a `A` instance as parameter. This `A` instance could be `$stub` (because `$stub` is a `A&Stub` instance).

```php
class A {

    public static function func(A $obj) {
        $helperData = $obj->helper();
        return $helperData + 1;
    }

    public function helper() {
        return 5;
    }
}

final class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFunc(): void
    {
        $stub = $this->createStub(A::class);

        $stub->method('helper')
            ->willReturn(2);

        $result = A::func($stub);
        $this->assertEquals(3, $result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: You are stubbing both of the methods--will this actually test any implementation of `A`? What if `func` does something more complicated than add 1 to the result of `helper`?

Comment: @yalpsideman Please see the second part of the updated answer.